# Functions involving expectations - The dominated/monotone convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $F:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a continuous function, $X$ and $Y$ two non-negative random variables on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, and

$$\mathbb{E}\big[\; F(X+Y) \;\big]<\infty$$

I am interested in the function

$$H(y)=\mathbb{E}\big[\; F(X+y) \;\big]$$

where $y\in[0,\infty)$. Is this function continuous? Is it continuous on some set $A\subset[0,\infty)$?

Intuitively, the random variable $F(X + y)$ is bounded on some (compact) set given by the random variable $Y$ and this should work.

If I understand corretly, those kind of continuity questions are usually answered via the dominated or monotone convergence theorem for Lebesgue integrals.

For example: given $y\in[0,\infty)$, we may take $y_{n}\rightarrow y$ and set $Z_{n}=F(X+y_{n})$, such that $Z_{n}\rightarrow Z=F(X+y)$. For dominated convergence however, we would need the $Z_{n}$ to be bounded by some integrable random variable.

Can anybody point me in the right direction or get me started?

Your help is highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the function $F$ is uniformly continuous, then the function $H$ is uniformly continuous.

Things become harder if we only consider continuity. We have to determine whether for any real number $x$ and any sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converging to $x$, the sequence $\left(h\left(x_n\right)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to $h(x)$ or not. 
We know that $F(X+x_n)$ converges pointwise to $F\left(X+x\right)$ by continuity of $F$. What misses to convert a pointwise convergence into a convergence in $\mathbb L^1$ is uniform integrability. We thus have continuity of $F$ if and only if 
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R, \forall \left(x_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}\mbox{  converging to }x, \left\{F\left(X+x_n\right),n\geqslant 1\right\}\mbox{ is uniformly integrable}.
$$